# Problems with Testcafe LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, local-storage, testcafe

everyone!
I'm new to TestCafe and I need some help on something I want to achieve.

I have a React website where I put a Facebook Login. Normally, when you enter the page and click on `Login with facebook` a popup window opens and enter your credentials normally. After that, you are redirected to the page and the token is saved in a `localStorage` variable for the page to consult later on.

However, when I run test for login process, Testcafe instead of opening a popup window, opens the facebook form on the same page and never redirects to the page.

Also, I tried to set some `dummy token` on the localstorage using the `ClientFunction` (and also `Roles`) and my website can never reach that token because testcafe seems to put this variable on a key called `hammerhead`

So, my question here is, how could I enter this token on the test or manually so my website can read it and make some functions with it?

This is what I have so far.

```
/* global test, fixture */
import { WelcomePage } from './pages/welcome-page'
import {ClientFunction, Role} from 'testcafe';

const welcomePage = new WelcomePage()

const setLocalStorageItem = ClientFunction((prop, value) => {
  localStorage.setItem(prop, value);
});

const facebookAccUser = Role(`https//mypage.net/`, async t => {
  await setLocalStorageItem('token', 'my-token');
}, { preserveUrl: true });

fixture`Check certain elements`.page(`https//mypage.net/`)
test('Check element is there', async (t) => {
  await t
    .navigateTo(`https//mypage.net/`)
    .wait(4000)
    .useRole(facebookAccUser)
    .expect(cetainElementIfLoggedIn)
    .eql(certainValue)
    .wait(10000)
})
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE FROM FEB 2021**

TestCafe now supports multiple browser windows and you can log-in via the Facebook popup form without any issues. Refer to the [Multiple Browser Windows](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows.html) topic for more information.

---

Currently, TestCafe does not support multiple browser windows. So it's impossible to log in via the Facebook popup form.
However, there is a workaround. Please refer to the following thread https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/1428.

My working test look like this:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const patchAuth = ClientFunction(() => {
    window['op' + 'en'] = function (url) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

        iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
        iframe.style.left = '200px';
        iframe.style.top = '150px';
        iframe.style.width = '400px';
        iframe.style.height = '300px';
        iframe.style['z-index'] = '99999999';
        iframe.src = url;
        iframe.id = 'auth-iframe';

        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    };
});

fixture `fixture`
    .page `https://www.soudfa.com/signup`;

test('test', async t => {
    await patchAuth();

    await t
        .click('button.facebook')
        .switchToIframe('#auth-iframe')
        .typeText('#email', '****')
        .typeText('#pass', '****')
        .click('#u_0_0')
        .wait(30e3);
});
```

Please keep in mind that manipulations with `x-frame-options` in the `testcafe-hammerhead` module are required.

In addition, I would like to mention that `Testing in Multiple browser windows` is one of our priority tasks, which is a part of [TestCafe Roadmap](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/roadmap/)